# Cannot Get Ported Over Website to New Win2008 Server to Launch

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, visual-studio-2010

We have an old Windows 2003 server that we are shutting down soon.

I am a C# Software Developer, so I use IIS a little. Everyone else here is Apache, so this job is falling on me.

I've got IIS7 installed, and I used Visual Studio 2010 to copy the web application to the E: drive of our new server.

I've got the Default Web Site stopped and our web application loaded up as one of the sites and turned on.

But, when I try to **Browse Web Site**, all I get is "This page can't be displayed"

I understand some things about IIS, but mostly from a developer's point of view - not an administrators.

Could someone give me pointers on what to look for to get this going?

[image: screenshot]

IIS7 asked what Host name I wanted to give it under the bindings. I used the Server's IP Address, then gave it `deveng.xxxxxxx.com` (where `xxxxxxx.com` is our company's website), but when I try to ping that, I get that ping could not find it.

[image: screenshot2]

I get the feeling that this is something simple like a DNS issue, but I don't know how to resolve that.

Do I need to add this server to our DNS server?

**UPDATE:**

I deleted the **Host name** in the Bindings, and now the page displays fine:

[image: sc binding]

I just need to find a way to map the IP address to a Hostname on our DNS server.

Answer (score 1):

Check the bindings on the new website. Is it bound to port 80?

If you re-enable the default website can you browse it?

Comment: The default website is browseable. It just shows the IIS7 image. I specified in the Bindings for the new site to use Port 80, but I don't know where else that may or may not need to be added/configured.

Comment: I just updated this. Removing the Hostname allowed the page to load, but now I need to assign the hostname to the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the **Host name** in the Bindings, and now the page displays fine:

[image: sc binding]

After I find a way to map the IP address to a Hostname on our DNS server, this machine should be all setup.